# Unable to render image based off prop from axios call in React web app

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to render an image using template literals, with the result of a database query used in the src of an image.

However, the template literal is being transformed into a pure string. It feels like a basic problem, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the render function in my component:

```
const fetchLoans = this.state.debts.map(debt => {


      return (<div className="individual-loan-amount-outstanding" key={debt._id}>
        <img className="individual-loan-picture" src={('../../../images/${debt.provider}.png')} alt="Provider of loan."/>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It would good to understand what your current setup looks like. Are these images in a "public" folder? Are you using `webpack`, if so, do you have a loader setup? Are you using create react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you aren't using backticks in the template?

```
    <img
      className="individual-loan-picture"
      src={`../../../images/${debt.provider}.png`}
      alt="Provider of loan."
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'` with `:

```
const fetchLoans = this.state.debts.map((debt) => {
    return (
        <div className="individual-loan-amount-outstanding" key={debt._id}>
            <img className="individual-loan-picture" src={`../../../images/${debt.provider}.png`} alt="Provider of loan." />
        </div>
    );
});
```